# nodemon:expressjs app not starting clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemon

I have generated express application with `express-generator` ,everything works fine until i deleted the `node_modules` folder.

after reinstall the node-modules `nodemon` is not starting the application.

> [nodemon] starting `node app.js` [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for
>   changes before restart

Here is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "build": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "csurf": "^1.9.0",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.15.5",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"
  },
  "main": "app.js",

}
```

Comment: possibilities are your other code file contains issue in code.
or try deleting package lock json then try to run it

Comment: deleted `package-lock.json`  but still the same

Comment: can you put reproducable sample code in git repo and send so it will be better to analyse the root cause

Comment: here is the github repo https://github.com/Shamonshamonsha/jenkins-test

Comment: @harshzalavadiya have found the issue?

Comment: then why its not work for me:)

Comment: sorry, got the issue posting it in solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an issue of nodemon, this error occurs when the file you are running with nodemon is ended its execution(i.e. scripts that do not run continuously).

I have cloned your repo and working fine for me so you should be running `nodemon app.js`.

[image: Server running]

If you are generating app with express generator your app.js is not the file that listens to the server. Actually, `bin/www` file is the one that starts listening and the app only create server object.

So `nodemon ./bin/www` should do the trick for you.

you can also edit package.json and add following in the code

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www"
}
```

And then run `npm run dev`.

Comment: I am getting same issue but editing package.json is not working for me

Answer (score 3):

you can modify your package.json and make it running.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "build": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
```

and then you can run your app normally with

```
npm build
```

because nodemon generally executes the `npm start` command and starts watching your files when you run `nodemon` but from express 4 running `node app.js` doesn't seems to be working anymore

you can modify package.json build command but don't modify start command because when you are deploying it to the production generally it will execute `npm start` and as production environment generally won't be having nodemon